# Run Many instance of phpScheduleIt in different folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, phpscheduleit

I want to run many instance of phpScheduleIt script (PHP script with lots of PHP files) in different folders.
I have tried some .htaccess codes but they does not work.
Can you please check these codes and point me if anything wrong?
(I'm testing in wamp server localhost)
I'm sorry I have little knowledge in .htaccess

Try One:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Domain.com/FakeScriptPath
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://Domain.com/RealScriptPath [P]
```

Try Two:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Domain\.com\/FakeScriptPath$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/Domain\.com\/RealScriptPath " [L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` contains the host header `domain.com` without path segment, so you need to match against url path in RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Domain.com$
RewriteRule ^FakeScriptPath http://Domain.com/RealScriptPath [P]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it to work after just adding "/" to end of "RealScriptPath /". 
But now it keep redirecting because "http://Domain.com/RealScriptPath" redirect to "http://Domain.com/RealScriptPath/web" and then because the path in address-bar is "http://Domain.com/FakeScriptPath/web" it again redirect to "http://Domain.com/RealScriptPath" and keep going.

So how to redirect ONLY "http://Domain.com/FakeScriptPath/index.php"?